# how can this function "resizeColumnscore" resizes image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to know how can this function(from MATLAB) resize the columns of an input image using weights an indices previously computed.

Which equations uses to do that?

```
resizeColumnsCore(double(in), weights', indices');
```

Answer (score 2):

When I looked for a function called `resizeColumnsCore` in MATLAB 7.11.0 (R2010b) I didn't find anything. However, I did find a [MEX-file](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html) by that name in MATLAB 7.8.0 (R2009a) in this subdirectory of the [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/):

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\images\images\private\
```

I guess they've phased it out or replaced it with another function in newer MATLAB versions. Now, if you want to know what the MEX-file does, you need to look at the source code it is compiled from. Luckily, it appears that this source code `resizeColumnsCore.cpp` can be found in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\images\images\private\src\misc\
```

And you can look through that code to determine the algorithms used to resize the columns of an image  given a set of weights and indices.

Now, if you want to know how these input arguments to `resizeColumnsCore` are computed, you'll have to look at the code of a function that calls it. I know of at least one function in the IPT that calls this function: [IMRESIZE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imresize.html). If you type `edit imresize` at the command prompt it will open that function in the Editor, allowing you to look through the code so you can see how the arguments to `resizeColumnsCore` are created.

What I can tell you for R2009a is that there is a subfunction in the file `imresize.m` called `contributions` which computes the weights and indices that are ultimately passed as arguments to `resizeColumnsCore`. That is where you will want to start looking to determine what algorithms are used to compute these arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't a proprietary MATLAB function.  Could we see some code or a link to the code?